# How can I access the text of Html.ValidationMessage() to check it in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, validationmessage

I have some code to booking tickets on movie. If somebody already booked ticket he may book more tickets, *only if there is specific error message*.

This var validationSummary receives only the tags (`<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Saving" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`). But in the web page @validationSummary prints correct message.
**How can I and can I access the text of the error message to check it at all?**

```
@{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    var validationSummary = Html.ValidationMessage("Saving");
    bool buyAnotherVal = validationSummary.ToString().Contains("By continuing this form, you will booking another some tickets");
 }
 @using ( Html.BeginUmbracoForm<MovieBookingSurfaceController>( "SubmitBuyerDetails", new { buyAnother = buyAnotherVal }) )
 {
    @validationSummary
```

Comment: Have you want to read `@validationSummary` in client-side? I think you can split message string to create string array and do something with that array by using client-side scripting.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, no, I need check it on the server side to get the buyAnotherVal result in the parameters of the SubmitBuyerDetails action

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto or it called client side if in Razor .cshtml page?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem so:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
var validationSummary = Html.ValidationMessage("Saving");
bool bookAnotherVal = Html.ValidationSummary().ToString().Contains(BookingException.Msg_EmailDuplicatedBookAnother);
```

The ValidationSummary method displays a list of all validation messages on the page. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx)